# trying to format my xml in notepad++ I recived 'EntityRef expecting ;' error

Tags: xml, notepad++

Trying to format my xml in notepad++ I recived this error :

EntityRef expecting ';'

when I used 'Check XML syntax now'

please tell me how to deal with it.

Comment: We'd need to see the actual XML to help. I'd suggest however that you check your XML syntax.

Comment: It's because you have a literal ampersand in your XML. Replace all literal ampersands with &amp;

Comment: thanks Daniel, it worked, just could you tell me how you detected it?

Comment: The error told me. Entity references start with `&` and end with `;`. If it was expecting an `;`, but didn't find one the most likely issue is an ampersand that isn't escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a literal ampersand in your XML. Replace all literal ampersands with `&amp;`.